# Attach a parsed email.message.Message instance to a created email.mime.multipart instance as payload in Python

Tags: python, email, mime, email-attachments

I haven't been able to find a solution to this particular problem on stackexchange or Google so far.

There are many examples of attaching files to multipart messages in Python, but **I want to extract an attachment from a parsed message and then re-attach it to a new multipart e-mail**.

After my interpretation of the docs, this is how I go about performing this task, demonstrated in a small working test script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from email.parser import Parser
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

email = Parser().parse(sys.stdin)

payloads = email.get_payload()

newMail = MIMEMultipart()
newMail['From'] = 'me@domain.tld'
newMail['Subject'] = 'Some subject'
newMail['To'] = 'someguy@ibm.com'
newMail.preamble = 'You need a MIME reader'

for p in payloads:
    p.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='att.eml')
    newMail.attach(p)

body = MIMEText('This is some body')
newMail.attach(body)

o = open('testoutput', 'w')
o.write(newMail.as_string())
o.close()

sys.exit(0)
```

This is actually a successful test, looks just as intended when I inspect the resulting testoutput file.

However, [here's the code](https://github.com/swehack/devops/blob/master/spam/spamutbildning.py) I'm trying to make work and it fails with the following message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../devops/spam/spamutbildning.py", line 232, in <module>
    if main():
  File "../devops/spam/spamutbildning.py", line 127, in main
    messageText = newMail.as_string()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/message.py", line 135, in as_string
    g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/generator.py", line 83, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/generator.py", line 115, in _write
    self._write_headers(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/generator.py", line 161, in _write_headers
    header_name=h, continuation_ws='\t').encode()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/header.py", line 403, in encode
    return self._encode_chunks(newchunks, maxlinelen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/header.py", line 363, in _encode_chunks
    _max_append(chunks, s, maxlinelen, extra)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/quoprimime.py", line 97, in _max_append
    L.append(s.lstrip())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lstrip'
```

I don't understand the relation between `newMail.as_string()` on line 127 and this tuple that I'm trying to use as a string.

Edit: I can't answer my own question but I have identified the problem. Specifically the use of `__setitem__` in the `Message` object.

It's supposed to go like this.

```
msg['from'] = 'from me'
```

Which is what I was doing, but when I switched to using add_header instead, it worked much better. Whenever I used the short form [..]=foo I got the tuple error.

Comment: i couldn't reproduce this with your code. works perfectly with every test mail i've tried, maybe it's a problem with the message you're using? otherwise use the debugger to set a breakpoint on `email/quoprimime.py:97` and try to find out why `s` is a tuple instead of a string.

Comment: @mata And I assume you used the larger program that I linked and not the test program I pasted into my post? I'm surprised at this revelation but I will try to do some break point debugging. Thank you for helping.

Comment: no, I used the program you posted and just piped a few test mails into stdin, it worked with every multipart message I tried.

Comment: @mata Yes the testprogram works fine, which is why I can't figure out the problem here. The testprogram tries to re-create the larger program I linked to by simply doing the email parsing and payload attachment. Still though, I think your suggestion of doing some debugging in the python files for the email package is best for now.